# The cleanest way to do HTTP POST with Basic authentication in Java?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication

What is the cleanest way to do HTTP POST with Basic Authentification in Java?

Comment: You should delete this question and split it into two, showing the work or research you've done in each.

Answer (score 0):

'Cleanest' is in the eye of the beholder, but you can do the first part with URL, HttpURLConnection, and an Authenticator. The second part belongs in a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

```
When user tries to login the application , based on the information in database pull the username and password for that particular user.
1) Check whether user is present in DB , if not available then return that USER does not exists.
2)If user is present in DB the pull the password for the USER and compare that against the password which is posted by the user through html/jsp. If its same then allow the user to login else return that password is incorrect.
3)If both username and password are correct as compared to what is present in DB then allows access to home page of appliaction.

Also there are ways using XML :
Security is also maintained by making secure the web page access using the jdbc realm :
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>jdbcRealm</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secure Pages</web-resource-name>
        <description/>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMINS</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```